# How to get blog post id in Widget blogger

Tags: blogger

in my blogger with using widget Popular post with loop value , so can i get post id in popular post to custom with my script

```
 <b:section id='viewed' showaddelement='no'>
                  <b:widget id='PopularPosts1' locked='true' title='Popular Posts' type='PopularPosts'>
                    <b:includable id='main'>
                      <b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
                        <div class='smallpost1'>
                          <b:if cond='data:post.thumbnail'>
                            <a expr:href='data:post.href' target='_blank'>
                              <img class='postimage2' expr:src='data:post.thumbnail' height='40' width='40'/>
                            </a>
                          </b:if>
                          <h3>
                            <a expr:href='data:post.href'>
                              <data:post.title/>
                            </a>
                          </h3>
                          <div class='clear'/>
                        </div>
                      </b:loop>
                      <b:include name='quickedit'/>
                    </b:includable>
                  </b:widget>
                </b:section>
```

ex: in tag

```
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
```

can in using post id :

```
<data:post.id/>
```

thanks for any suggest

Comment: I'm not sure what is your question. Are you asking if inside that loop can you use <data:post.id/>?

Comment: yes , i want asking can using <data:post.id/> inside loop !

Comment: Looking at http://support.google.com/blogger/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47270 it should work, but I tried and only the <data:post.title/> seems to work. I suggest you try to ask in Blogger Forum related to templates at http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/blogger/layouts--templates

Answer (score 2):

For all who maybe still interested how to fix this:

You need to add `showaddelement='no'` in the `<b:widget...>` on line 2

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the unique id for each post you can get it by following the steps below:
Open the post for which you want the Id with the editor. Then copy the post id from the url.[image]

If you are referring to something else please let us know.